# How to use DriveApp to change folder color?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I would like to dynamically modify the color of my Google drive folders based on whether or not there are files that exist in the folder.  Currently, using the DriveApp.Folder api, I don't see a way to do so? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

With Drive Advanced Service you can query the Drive API to set the `folderColorRgb` to the color you want. You have to take care as the color can only be one of the colors pre defined by Google.

Now when you use Advanced Services you have to use a dedicated GCP project to activate the API, to avoid that I made a script that query directly the Drive API. Better for people that use the DriveApp service in Apps Script, no need for GCP project.

Explanation here : https://medium.com/@stephane.giron/change-google-drive-folder-color-with-apps-script-259743ab1c30

GitHub : https://github.com/St3ph-fr/my-apps-script-utils/blob/master/Drive/Manage_Folder_Color.js

Answer (score -1):

As you've found, you cannot get or set the color of a folder (or file) through DriveApp (nor the DocsList Class). The Drive SDK does not provide access to these either, so it's not possible to code a work-around using that API.

You may wish to add an issue to the [Google Apps Script Issue Tracker](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/), requesting support for this capability.

Answer (score -1):

[St3ph's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55971524) is very well-rounded. But if you are looking for a simpler method, the following line of code will return the folder color:

```
Drive.Files.get('folderId', {'fields': 'folderColorRgb', supportsAllDrives: 'true' }).folderColorRgb;
```

This is for directly in the Google Apps Script code editor with Drive API (v2) turned on. The folder color returned is the one set by the user executing the script as each user can set and see their unique color. This code also supports folders in Shared Drives.